# stdint.h for Java?

Tags: java, stdint

Is there a java library implementing the standard data types as they are available in C?

In Java everything is signed, so using `byte` to store `uint8_t` comes with some problems, for example:

```
byte test = (byte) 0xf3;
System.out.println("test = " + test);
```

prints

```
test = -13
```

instead of

```
test = 243
```

I think of something like this:

```
UInt8 test = new UInt8(0xf3);
System.out.println("test = " + test.toInt());
```

Comment: Did you try `unsigned` or `unsigned byte` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, Java doesn't have unsigned primitive types, and it's a headache when talking to embedded hardware.

Comment: @chrylis `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @arshajii True, I forget that `char` does technically count as an integral type.

Comment: It's just a representation (a convention): 0xf3 == -13, where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

there's a workaround, try `System.out.println("test = " + (0xff & test));` you'll get 243

Comment: ok, but how would you use this in a code where `test` can be dynamic? it seems a little tricky to me..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any good library that implements C/POSIX standard datatypes.

Recently I had to use predefined POSIX constants such as `S_IREAD` or `S_IFDIR` in a Java program and I had to create my own constants list class...

As @Evgeniy Dorofeev suggested, try to find workarounds :)